# How to set top margin to one window length?

Tags: html, css, window, margin

I want to make an element, i.e. a box I made in css, show up just out of frame or have a top margin value of one full window length.

Here's a website link for a working example: http://www.pulse8music.com/bestofchillstep2014
Referencing the linked website, I would like to replicate the white background area starting just out of frame, causing the user to discover the white area by scrolling. Thank you for your time.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Stylesheet.css"></link>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "titleBar">
            <p class = "title">title</p>
        </div>
        <div class = "targetBox">
            <p class = "longboxTitle">title</p>
            <p class = "longboxSubtitle">subtitle</p>
            <div class = "box"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
.targetBox {
    height: 40cm;
    width: auto;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    background-size: 100%;
    margin-right: -3000px;
    padding-right: 3000px;
    margin-left: -3000px;
    padding-left: 3000px;
    /* INSERT NEW CODE HERE */
}
```

Comment: Wow! AMAZING site! That is absolutely incredible! bravo!

Comment: I'll make sure to tell the creator. I'm merely using his beautiful site as an example for what I'd like to accomplish.

Comment: Ok. Just keep in mind anybody can make a website as stunning as that, just keep trying, and whatever you want to make will be made!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use css’ *vh* unit (viewport height) for this.
*1vh* equals 1 percent of the viewports (the browser windows) width, so setting the height to *height: 100vh* would pretty muhc do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Although seemingly illogical, I found `height:100%` to work in this situation.

---

## Good Luck on this beautiful site!

Comment: Unfortunately this resized the box to a thin strip and positioned it at the top of the page. The white box in the example link is what I'm trying to replicate in this website. Thanks for the feedback never the less.

Comment: How did you position the box?

Comment: I never defined a position so it's using the default. The answer to my problem is to use margin-top: 100vh;

Comment: Oh... Ok then. My method only works on predefined X and Y, because it moves down from the current X coord.